# is there some easy way to include custom fonts in xml field declaration?

Tags: android, android-widget

I included in created fonts folder in /assets and added some files  .otf and .ttf. Is possible to create style and attach one of those fonts to some TextViews. I now to do this from code 
like

```
 Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/BPreplayBold.otf");
         tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.key2);

           tv2.setTypeface(tf2);
```

but is there some easier way to do this in xml, to include custom fonts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `TextView`

```
class TypedTextView() extends TextView {
  public TypedTextView(...) {
    super(...);
    this.setTypeFace(...)
  }
```

And then use this widget in your XML layout

```
<com.exemple.com.TypedTextView>Hello with nice font</com.exemple.com.TypedTextView>
```

If you do things properly, I suppose you can get/set the font thanks to a custom XML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use custom fonts is through the source code.